# Calling Swift 4 generic method produce error

Tags: swift, generics, swift4.1

Given the following method to a Dictionary like class (Lets say the Table class) where the key and value are both data type that conforms to the protocol Value. Number types, String, Bool, and etc are extended to conform to the Value protocol.

```
open class Table: StoredValue {
...
        open func asDictionary<K1: Value, V1: Value, K2: Value, V2: Value>(
            _ kfn: (K1) -> K2 = {$0 as! K2},
            _ vfn: (V1) -> V2 = {$0 as! V2}
        ) -> [K2: V2] where K2: Hashable {

        var v = [K2: V2]()
        for key in keys() {
            let val = self[key]
            if key is K1 && val is V1 {
                v[kfn(key as! K1)] = vfn(val as! V1)
            }
        }
        return v
    }
}
```

The Table class itself is not a generic class but the methods for converting to native Swift container classes are generic.

The issue is calling the method from my code. I have tried to use various way to call the method, I just can't get it to work. Googling did not find any solutions either. I believe it works prior to Swift 4.x but something has change.

For example:

Calling the method with the default conversation closure as such:

```
let dict  = options.asDictionary()
```

Xcode will complain (rightly so) with the error "Generic parameter 'K1' could not be inferred"

Calling the method with the target type as such:

```
let dict: [String: Any] = options.asDictionary()
```

Xcode will complain with the error "Cannot convert value of type '[_ : _]' to specified type '[String : Any]'"

Supplying the conversion closure like this:

```
let dict: [String: Any] = options.asDictionary({ $0 as! String }, { $0 as Any })
```

Xcode complains with the error "Expression type 'String' is ambiguous without more context"

Is the generic method definition wrong?

Comment: I think you're complicating this by doing 2 things at once (creating a dictionary, and mapping the keys/values)

Comment: The problem with `let dict: [String: Any] = options.asDictionary()` is that `K2` and `V2` are inferred (as `String` and `Any`, respectively), but `K1` and `V2` could be anything.

Comment: @Alexander Any suggestions to do it differently?

Comment: @Alexander I realized that K1 and V1 is ambiguous but I don’t know how to explicitly specify the type of the two generic argument.

Comment: Well lets break it down. Why do K1 and V1 exist, at all?

Comment: @Alexander Interesting question. I’ve never given it much thought apart from having to translate from K1 to K2 and V1 to V2. Now I’m thinking it may work if I leave it out of the definition all together. I’ll give it a try when I’m back in front of my computer later. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170566/discussion-between-alexander-and-weyhan-ng).